# Azure DevOps Agent Pool approvals and checks - where to give the approval?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using the Azure DevOps Agent Pool "Azure Pipelines".
When I went to "Project setting" > "Agent pools" > "Azure Pipelines" and select in the top right corner the "three dots" - there I can select "Approvals and checks" on Pool level.

I've added there an approval, so that approvers should grant all deployments which are triggered for the agent pool "Azure Pipelines".

Now, when I will run a Pipelines using that Pool it's immediately failing and I couldn't find the place where I could give the approval:

```
##[error]The job is using protected resource(s) for which checks have not been evaluated queue:Azure Pipelines. For more details, refer to https://aka.ms/pipelinechecks.
```

Behind the link https://aka.ms/pipelinechecks I couldn't find anything regarding **Agent pool approvals**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a build needs your approval. The approval button is in the Summary page of the queued build.

If you trigger a build that needs youself to approve. You can **refresh** the page or wait for a while until you see `1 approval needs your review before this run can continue` appears on the build **Summary** page. Then click **Review** and choose to approve

[image]

Comment: I guess this is the case when you add Post-deployment approval, which is not my case. I've added the approval on agent pool level. And then when I trigger a build it's directly running into the error. So, it is not waiting for approval and there is no opportunity like in your screenshot.

Comment: I actually followed your steps to add the approvals on the agent pool level. But i cannot reproduce your scenario. Can you create a test pipeline to run on azure pipelines agent pool to check if this issue happens to all pipelines?

Comment: I tried to create a release pipline which leads me into the following issue: `The stage refers to resources like queue 'Azure Pipelines', that have been protected with checks. Protected resources can only be used in YAML pipelines. For more details, refer to https://aka.ms/pipelinechecks.` Then I added the "Starter Pipeline" which is working as you said ... but I didn't get teh differencies between those two ... hm...

Comment: lol I found it - when referencing the pool I used a variable `pool: vmImage: $(vmImage)` which is set to 'ubuntu-latest' -> when I change this directly to the value 'ubuntu-latest' instead of using the varaible it's running - so it seems to me a bug ...

Comment: That is great you found it. You can arrange it as an answer.